# React Native - useState in HTML

Tags: react-native, printing, expo

I am trying to use expo-print to print out some stored data, the problem is that on Android, expo-print can only print html data that you pass into it, and I do not know how to pass information from a state into html.

Here is a snack of what im doing (line 143): https://snack.expo.dev/@vevlex/print-usage

Can someone explain to me how to do this, or another way to go about it?
Thank you in advance,
Patryk

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just missing the dollar sign for the string interpolation:

```
const html = `
  <html>
    <body>
      <h1 style="text-align:center;">${toPrint.client}</h1>
    </body>
  </html>
`;
```